# Why is it continuing to repeat the while True even though I have broken it?

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, pickle, break

```
...
elif error.lower() == 'create':
    while True:
        try:
            username = raw_input('What would you like your username to be?  ')
            username2 = raw_input('Please enter the same username again: ')
            while not pickle.load(open("%s.p"%username, "rb"))[1]:
                break
                break
            else:
                pickle.load(open("","rb"))
        except IOError:
            print 'The username is not available. Please try a different one.'
    pword = getpass('What would you like your password to be?  ')
    pword2 = getpass('Please enter the same password again: ')
    while pword != pword2:
          print 'The passwords do not match.'
          pword = getpass('What would you like your password to be?  ')
          pword2 = getpass('Please enter the same password again: ')
    money_left = 0
    isguest = False
    print 'Your username is %s, and your password is %s. You have $%d ingame money.' % (username, pword, money_left)
...
```

When I am trying to create an account in my while True, I am making sure the username is available before registering it. It works and asks me again if the username is not available, but even if it is, it still keeps asking. Can you help me?

Comment: You're only breaking out of the `while not pickle.load` loop, you never break out of `while True:`.

Comment: If you thought the second `break` would do that, you were wrong. It never gets executed, since the first break causes all the code inside the inner loop to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` statement(s) break out of the `while not...` statement, not the `while True` loop.  I suspect that you meant to write:

```
if not pickle.load(open("%s.p"%username, "rb"))[1]:
    break
```

The documentation on `break` is [here.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

I made some adjustments to your code.  See if this works for you:

```
import os.path
while True:
    username = raw_input('What would you like your username to be?  ')
    if os.path.exists("%s.p" % username):
        print 'The username "%s" is not available. Please try a different one.' % (username,)
        continue
    username2 = raw_input('Please enter the same username again: ')
    if username == username2:
        break
    else:
        print "The usernames don't match.  Try again."

while True:
    pword = raw_input('What would you like your password to be?  ')
    pword2 = raw_input('Please enter the same password again: ')
    if pword == pword2:
        break
    else:
        print 'The passwords do not match. Try again.'

money_left = 0
isguest = False
print 'Your username is %s, and your password is %s. You have $%d ingame money.' % (username, pword, money_left)
```